# What if you have the Dragonborn DLC?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

What if you use the “Bend Will” shout on a dragon and fly there? It should work, right?

Comment: The question is too vague. I'm guessing you mean the game The Elder Scrolls: Skyrim? Make sure to tag your question appropriately.  
What is the situation of your question? Fly where? To do what?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are asking if you can fly to Solstheim, the main area in the Dragonborn DLC. If that is the case, then that is not possible.

> As travel in any one direction is not possible, dragons cannot be used in place of a traditional mount, such as a horse. It is possible to fast travel while mounted on a dragon, **however travel between Skyrim and Solstheim is not possible**
>
> <sub>[Dragon Riding wiki](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Dragon_Riding)</sub>